# Python Pandas, groupby() and sum() values without column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question about counting items in a Pandas Dataframe

I have a Python Dataframe `df` which lists events per day

```
Date           Week        Eventdetails
01-09-2011    01-07-2011     ....
01-10-2011    01-07-2011     ....
01-11-2011    01-07-2011     ....
01-12-2011    01-07-2011     ....
01-12-2011    01-07-2011     ....
01-15-2011    01-14-2011     ....
```

I am not summing any value in a column; I am simply trying to the number of times "Week" occurs, e.g. above there are 5 events in the week of 01-07-2011.

I should somehow use `df.grouby("Week")`, but how do I sum?

Comment: `df.groupby('Week').count()` ought to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for size rather than sum:

```
In [11]: df.groupby("Week").size()
Out[11]:
Week
01-07-2011    5
01-14-2011    1
dtype: int64
```

---

If Date were an index/DatetimeIndex, you could resample:

```
In [21]: df1
Out[21]:
                  Week Eventdetails
Date
2011-01-09  01-07-2011         ....
2011-01-10  01-07-2011         ....
2011-01-11  01-07-2011         ....
2011-01-12  01-07-2011         ....
2011-01-12  01-07-2011         ....
2011-01-15  01-14-2011         ....

In [22]: df1.resample("W", how="size")
Out[22]:
Date
2011-01-09    1
2011-01-16    5
Freq: W-SUN, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I get a TypeError
`TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex`

Comment: @ShanZhengYang yes, like I say for the resample you need a DatetimeIndex. i.e. do `df.set_index("Date", inplace=True); df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I should somehow use `df.grouby("Week")`, but how do I sum?

```
df.groupby('Week').sum()
```

Although based on your expected output I believe you would like to use `.count()`.